# What are good plants for sandy soil?

Tags: soil, plant-recommendations

I live in the San Francisco Bay area and my landlord asked us to take care of the overgrown yard in exchange for reduced rent. I cleared a lot of the dead weeds and piles of leaves out and it looks like the soil is mostly sand (we live near a beach, so that makes sense). Any plants I can put in that patch that will keep the wind from kicking up dirt/sand?

I suppose I could cover it with topsoil, but maybe keeping the soil the way it is and using plants that are conducive to that environment would be lower maintenance.

Comment: If you live close to beach, you might want to check if the soil contain too much salt first.

Answer (score 5):

Sandy soil drains more quickly than silt or clay, so choose plants that require little watering.

A layer of mulch can help retain moisture.

[**Rosemary**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosemary) is a fragrant herb suited to the San Francisco Bay area as it requires very little watering. Its Latin name (*Rosmarinus officinalis*) literally translates to 'dew of the sea' as it can live off of the humidity of the sea breeze.

Answer (score 3):

Look to nature. Have a look at uncultivated areas with similar soil types. The plants that are growing naturally will certainly grow when cultivated.

Eg. If you live in a desert, cactus will grow well.

There are several other options available depending on how much effort/money you want to invest:

1. **Water more often**. Like Ambo100 said, sandy soil will drain faster. Watering will keep it moist and allow a greater number of plants to grow and flourish.
2. **Mulch the area**. This site has a huge number of questions on mulch like [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/185/how-much-mulch-should-i-put-in-my-vegetable-gardens), [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4410/what-herbaceous-plants-like-acid-soil-blueberries-and-white-pine-mulch) and [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/474/how-should-i-use-corrugated-cardboard-for-mulch). This will help the soil retain water. Mulching or composting is great for the environment too.
3. **Use a sand converter**. I live in a sandy area of Australia, similar to California. My local garden supplier stocks a product called "[Sand to Soil](http://www.richgro.com.au/products/my-garden/sand-to-soil/)" (Bentonite Clay). I didn't believe my retailer when they said "It changes the chemical composition of sand, making soil". But it does actually work. I would use the word "miracle"...

I highly recommend option 3. I did it a few weeks ago and the results are amazing.

Comment: The sand to soil link is broken.